# multiple notifications

Tags: android

I am developing task manager in android 2.1
I want to set multiple notification alerts but in my program when second notification gets displayed previous one gets cleared .plz help me as to show all notification say suppose after interval of 2 minutes..as intact...
my code
1) main activity

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "SomeApp ";
    protected Toast mToast;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // for using this you need to
                                                // import java.util.Calendar;

        // add minutes to the calendar object
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

        // cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
        // cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,10);
        // cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);

        // cal.set will set the alarm to trigger exactly at: 21:43, 5 May 2011
        // if you want to trigger the alarm after let's say 5 minutes after is
        // activated you need to put

        Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmintent.putExtra("title", "Title of ");
        alarmintent.putExtra("note", "Description of our  Notification");
        // HELLO_ID is a static variable that must be initialised at the
        // BEGINNING OF CLASS with 1;

        int HELLO_ID = 1;
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), HELLO_ID, alarmintent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | 

                  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // for using this you need to


                cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 17);

        // cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
        // cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,10);
        // cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);



        Intent alarmintent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmintent1.putExtra("title", "Title 2 ");
        alarmintent1.putExtra("note", "Description 2");


        int HELLO_ID1 = 2;
        PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), HELLO_ID1, alarmintent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | 
             Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);  

        AlarmManager am1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), sender1);
    }
```

2) Alarm receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String NotificationManager = null;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // NotificationManager mNotificationManager =

        // (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Combi Note", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(context, 
                  AlarmReceiver.class), 0); 

                   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String title = extras.getString("title");
        // here we get the title and description of our Notification
        //
        String note = extras.getString("note");
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        // here we set the default sound for our
        // notification

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
        // notification
        manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same notification id they will override each other.

Comment: thanks @gwa....it works but when i press clear tab all notificatins get cleared ..isit any way as to clear the notification which i widh and keep oters to read afterwards if i am busy....

Comment: No problem prakash_d22! You can flag them with FLAG_NO_CLEAR (notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;) but then you have to clear the notification that you click on explicitly using mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID); in the code where you land on...

Comment: I added the flag I was talking about, then check out this example for understanding how to clear the notification: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-notification-example
Hope it will help!